# How to refresh temp data in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

Actually, i have a page to edit the user profile. I am using TempData to keep the user name in navigation bar. So how can i refresh the TempData values, once the user made any changes (username) in edit profile page.

Controller Code :

```
         public ActionResult ProfileViewModel()
    {
        TempData.Keep()
        var Fname = TempData["FullName"];
        ViewData["FullName"] = Fname;
    }
```

The above code i used to keep the TempData until i logout. With this code i cant able to refresh the TempData. But i can able to get the changed values once i log out and log in.

So, How can i refresh the TempData values without log out.

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Update the value ? `TempData["FullName"]="some new value";` after saving the profile information ?

Comment: Yes, after saving i need to get the updated values

Comment: why are you keeping information that is valid for multiple calls in TempData?  TempData only lives for one time messages.  then you've got to copy into TempData again.  why not just keep it in session and overwrite the variable when it's changed?

Comment: Yeah, if no other option, i have to do with session @Fran

Comment: what's wrong with session?

Comment: Nothing wrong with session @Fran, But how to get the username from model using session. Can you give some code. In controller i used "Fullname = login.getFullname(login.username);" to get the username. So how can i use this with session to display in my view

Comment: Put the session value into a view model property in a controller action and pass the view model to the view.